# Removing missing features which are not referenced

Tags: 2007, feature, migration

I have an issue, basically I have one missing feature which was found by the pre upgrade tool and i would like to delete it, but no tools help me with that, it is also said that this feature is referenced no where:

> Name = ReportCenterSiteTemplate, Feature id =
>   fb4a43a8-55e3-4219-8a37-f5204880d3d9, Reference count = 0, Scope =
>   ScopeInvalid, Status = Missing

How can i find it and delete?

**Update** i found out that the feature is located in the Configuration Content Database, in the table objects.

Comment: did your try this one https://featureadmin.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: I did use the feature admin and it finds it, BUT i cannot delete it, it gives me an error "An error occured iterating through the features"

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `stsadm.exe`

If the feature is activated in any scope then it has to be deactivated, use the following command to deactivate it

```
stsadm –o deactivatefeature –id YourFeatureID -url YourSiteURL
```

Then you have to retract and delete the solution, using the following code,

```
stsadm -o retractsolution -name featuretester.wsp -immediate -url http://moss-1
stsadm -o exeadmsvcjobs
stsadm -o deletesolution -name featuretester.wsp
```

Have a look at the below links too,

[SharePoint: Don’t Forget to Uninstall the Feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/02/02/sharepoint-don-t-forget-to-uninstall-the-feature.aspx)

[How to Remove Orphaned Features Using PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8027.sharepoint-2007-how-to-remove-orphaned-features-using-powershell.aspx)

[Installing or Uninstalling Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442691%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: First of all i have no idea where the feature is, please read my post, second there is no solution for it etc ...

Comment: @Shkipper, try to delete the safe control entry of that feature from the web.config file and then try pre upgrade check. Can you use powershell in your environment.?

Comment: Yes, i can use powershell

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue, basically what I have done, i've created a feature folder in the features => like MyFeature/feature.xml.

The next step I used stsadm to install the feature:

```
stsadm -o installfeature -filename MyFeature\feature.xml
```

And the final step, i used the Feature Admin Tool to delete this feature.

Note: the feature XML you can define your own name or whatever you want and set it to be a farm, then you can easily locate this feature with Admin Feature Tool.